# Type ... was not registered in the serializer (non web app)

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus3

I am trying to send a command with NServiceBus 3.0.  Everything works when I send a command that implements ICommand.  However, it does not work if I use the conventions.  The source is below.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static NServiceBus.IBus Bus { get; private set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureBus();

        var command = new RouteTradeCommand() { TradeXml = "<trade />" };
        Bus.Send("BrokerQueue@DATPCDI041", command);
    }

    private static void ConfigureBus()
    {
        Bus = Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .UnicastBus()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Messages"))
            .SendOnly();
    }
}
```

The command looks like this:

```cs
namespace Messages
{
    public class RouteTradeCommand : IRouteTradeCommand
    {
        public string TradeXml { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately,
NSB is dependent on the ordering of the config methods. It'll work if you move the DefiningCommandsAs method to right after With:

```
NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Commands"))
.Log4Net()
.DefaultBuilder()
.XmlSerializer()
.MsmqTransport()
.DefineEndpointName("Web")
.UnicastBus()
.SendOnly();
```